# How can i call a Getter method from the main to my Jframe in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing

I'm stuck on this bit of code I'm trying to do. I've got a program I'm working in Netbeans with a main java form and a JFrame that acts like a popup. The frame has a button which prints the value of what I've put in a Getter method in the main. The is no error in the code put once i run the program and click the button the program crashes and this is what i get:

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)"
```

This is my code for the main: `

```
    public void Iva(){

    float tiv = Float.parseFloat(tiva);     // tiva is a global, String type variable

    if("Papeleria".equals(tiva)){

        iva = (float) (tiv*0.16);      // iva is a global Float type variable 

    }

    if("Supermercado".equals(tiva)){
         iva = (float) (tiv*0.12);
    }

    if("Supermercado".equals(tiva)){

         iva = (float) (tiv*0.14);
    }
    ivi = Float.toString(iva);     // ivi is a global, String type variable
}

public String getIva() {
    Iva();
    return ivi;
}
```

And this is what Ive got for the ActionPerformed in the Frame:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    /*taiva is the text area where i want to show iva
    mainy is what i called the main's class*/

    taiva.setText(mainy.getIva()); 
}
```

Comment: Not your down-voter (yet) but this whole set-up sounds sketchy, but it's hard to say since you've only partially described your program structure and have only posted snippets. For us to much more completely understand your problem, do consider creating and posting a ***small*** but functioning program that we can compile and run and that shows the problem for us, a valid [mcve], and posting the code in your question as code-formatted text.

Comment: Also understand that your use of a JFrame as a dialog window is not correct, that this should instead be a JDialog. Please read [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636) for more on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I will work on putting the frame's contents in a jDialog and will update my question to a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example once I'm done.

Comment: Thank you. Also note that Java doesn't have "global" variables, and if you mean that you're using static fields to allow multiple classes to share the data -- you shouldn't do this.

Comment: Hovercraft Full of Eels I've changed the frame and put it into a JDialog but it wont show when I press the button but only the top bar shows up I've already adjusted the minimum size

Comment: So again we're stuck with something being wrong in code not shown. Again a decent [mcve] would help wondrously.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is failing on this line of code:

```
float tiv = Float.parseFloat(tiva);     // tiva is a global, String type variable
```

You are trying to parse an empty string (`tiva`) which results in an `NumberFormatException`.

You can avoid this problem by using an if-statement, like this:

```
float tiv = 0;
if (!tiva.isEmpty()) {
  tiv = Float.parseFloat(tiva);
} else {
  tiv = 0;
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Likely he's got bigger design problems then this, and I'm betting that while this may rid him of the exception, it won't allow the program to work correctly.

Comment: (or maybe "she")

Comment: She and thank you Tostifrosti for explaining the error and giving me a solution. appreciate your help.

Comment: @DanielaVillamizar: again this will rid you of the error, but does this allow your program to function correctly?

Comment: yes sir it does but its not doing the math it just gives me 0.0?

Comment: @DanielaVillamizar: Exactly as I thought, so it does not allow your program to function correctly and you've still got deep design issues. You still need to create and post a valid [mcve] if you want more than a band-aid answer, one that gets your program actually working.

Comment: I'm a newbie but I've used the "multiple frames" method in many programs and i haven't run into issues. This is probably just an error in my calculations I'm trying to solve

Comment: @DanielaVillamizar: again all Tostifrosti is doing is putting a band-aid over the hidden error. Again if you want our help, you need to un-hide the error so we can see it. Til then, over and out.